# Yahoo YQL Finance quotes returns random data

Tags: php, json, curl, yql

I'm currently experiencing an issue with YQL, the quote data i get from yahoo.finance.quotes seems to be random. I've tried this from different IP addresses aswell, but with no change. Below is an url to access one of the quotes i'm trying to get:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%27ABB.ST%27&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

This returns a json encoded array with all stock data. However, if you keep accessing that particular url, you will see that the content is different every time. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Maybe the market is dynamic?

Comment: @Kisaragi Weird thing is that if you do this through the YQL console, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kisaragi if you look closely, you will notice the time stamps for LastTradeTime will jump around as well, as though its not always returning latest, there's not an option to make it return the latest trade, it's supposed to as far as I can tell

Comment: @CodedropTeam I'm noticing the same behavior in the console :/

Comment: This seems to be a caching issue on yahoo. The console is giving the latest trade time, but calling the api directly uses random quotes.Has anyone been able to solve this?